# Cant add tt_news plugin into folder as "use as container"

Tags: typo3, tt-news

I installed tt_news 3.6.0 into typo3 6.2.15. 
Extension installed successfully.

But i created folder in page tree and i want to use "Use as Container" in Behaviour tab and i dont see this plugin on list.

Any ideas what can be wrong ?

Comment: already cleared typo3 system cache?

Comment: Yes, i cleared cache via backend and also removed content of typo3tep/Cache

Comment: There is an issue on TYPO3 forge: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/62648 The two mentioned lines cure the symptom, but I doubt that this is the best and final solution.

Works here. ;-)